# Function to find a prime integer on R

Tags: r

Why isn't my R code working (i.e. doesn't find prime numbers)?

```
x <- c(1:50)
prime <- function(x){if(x %% (2:(x-1)) == 0) {
  print("p")
} 
else {
  print("np")
}}
```

Comment: `if` requires its condition to be length 1, yours is far beyond that. Perhaps `!any(x %% ...)`? Notably, if you included any of the warnings you get when trying your function, you would see `numerical expression has 50 elements: only the first used` which is hint #1, then `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`, which is included in many SO questions/answers, as is `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`.

Comment: BTW: a function like this that *prints* something is in my experience almost useless. Consider **`return`ing** a value instead of `print`ing one. Further, consider returning a logical (`TRUE` or `FALSE`).

Comment: And while my first comments hints at it -- assumine that `"p"` means prime and `"np"` means not-prime -- your logic is wrong. If there are any 0s in `x %% (2:(x-1))`, then it is *not* a prime, as it is divisible by something other than 1 and itself.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few issues here.

1. Per @r2evans comment, the if condition needs to take an input parameter of length 1. You can get around this using the `all` command.
2. Your if condition is logically wrong. If the mod operator is equal to 0 then it is NOT prime. If fact you want to do != 0.
3. 2 is considered to be a prime number. Your logic won't work for 2 because 2%2 = 0. As such you need to handle that case differently. Or the function needs to start working at 3.

Here is a working version:

```
prime <- function(x){
  if(x == 2){
    print("p")
  }
  else if(all(x %% (2:(x-1)) != 0)) {
  print("p")
} else {
    print("np")
  }
}


> prime(2)
[1] "p"
> prime(3)
[1] "p"
> prime(4)
[1] "np"
> prime(5)
[1] "p"
> prime(6)
[1] "np"
> prime(7)
[1] "p"
```

Comment: @r2evans: hah! typo. Fixed. Thanks for that!